# "The content requires the Adobe Flash Player" when using capybara-webkit in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, webkit, qt4, flash, sidekiq

We are trying to build an application that crawls through our internal app to warm up cache for flash content. We uses Sidekiq, Capybara-Webkit and Headless for it and found [this github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/659) particular useful to set this up. However, we are having trouble setting up QtWebkit(seems to be the rendering engine capybara-webkit uses) to load Adobe flash content. Does anyone have experience how to have capybara-webkit to load Adobe flash content?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Rails 4
- Sidekiq
- QT4

Comment: did you find something?

Comment: @AlexeyBrovikov we ended up going back to use selenium hub with firefox.